# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout Render Problem

Tags: android-studio, rendering, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

It just a Render Bug, So cant' work preview in android studio. But It run with properly.
If remove the CollapsingToolbarLayout then, it work rendering. but with CollapsingToolbarLayout not work rendering.

```
const val appcompatVersion = "1.2.0"
const val constraintVersion = "1.1.3"
const val materialVersion = "1.1.0"
```

It is a error message It is a error message It is a error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7200)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$Api21Impl$1.onApplyWindowInsets(ViewCompat.java:4774)
at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:10514)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7191)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
at com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.onAttachedToWindow(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:264)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19575)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I write the code below.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:elevation="0dp">
    
                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
    
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
    
                     //content

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
    
                       //Just View (I used this container like a toolbar)

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
   
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                        style="@style/TabLayout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Why trouble for me?**

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Invalidate caches/restart` ? Also, update your `ConstraintLayout` version: `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'`